# How to get first row of data in sqlite3 using php PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

How to get first row of data in sqlite3 using php PDO

As per my below code first row data does not display becuase I have used recordset for check row is return or not.

Any idea how to get all data from record set?

**My Code.**

```
    try {
        $dbhandle = new PDO("sqlite:".$database);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $result=$dbhandle->query("select * from table");

    if($result)
    {
        if($rs1==$result->fetchColumn())
        {
            while ($rs1 = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) 
            {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($rs1);
                echo "</pre>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // error message
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to get the first row, then there's no need to use a loop.

```
$result=$dbhandle->query("select * from table");
if ($result) {
  $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($row);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

***Update:***
For get all rows.

```
$result=$dbhandle->query("select * from table");
$rows = array();
if ($result) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $rows[] = $row;
  }
  if ($rows) {
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($rows);
     echo "</pre>";
  } else {
     echo "No results";
  }
}
```

Comment: No i want to get all data but I want to check query return any row or not so I have write code like this.