# Returning String from Query in PHP/SQLite

Tags: php, html, css, sqlite

I am attempting to create a cookie with the return string of this query:

```
$id = $database -> query("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
```

However, it is returning an object rather than a string. I am trying to return the "id" of the row. How do I do this?

Comment: By the way, here is the format of the cookie I am trying to create: setcookie("session", "$id", time()+3600);

Comment: I think so... $database = new PDO("sqlite:database.sqlite");

Comment: Yeah it is, try fetchColumn http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Comment: What happens when somebody enters the password `whatever' OR username = 'admin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an object because you `executed` the `query` only.

For this you have to fetch data from it,
Like

```
$result = $database -> query("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
```

then if you are using `sqlite` then,

```
$data = sqlite_fetch_array($result, SQLITE_ASSOC);
$id=$data['id'];
```

Refer http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-fetch-array.php

then `setcookie` like:

```
setcookie("session", "$id", time()+3600);
```

Refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

If you are using `PDO` then

try it like:

```
$result=$database->query("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
if ($result) {
  $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($row);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

Test this [How to get first row of data in sqlite3 using php PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170785/how-to-get-first-row-of-data-in-sqlite3-using-php-pdo)

Answer (score 1):

You can set what format PDO returns when fetching,

```
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
```

Or you can just return the column itself,

```
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the `array object` so that you can access the id string!

```
$id = $this->db->get()->row_array()->('id');
```

then you can use `$id` and set it in a `cookie`:

```
setcookie("session", "$id", time()+3600);
```

Comment: I see this code is for MySQL. I am using SQLite. How would this work in SQLite?